# how to resolve SMTP error in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django

i'm deploying my django project using pythonanywhere, in my code i will send an activation like to the user after he/she has opened an account, but that line isn't being run, i' getting an error which says:

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /
(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError q185sm6000383qke.25 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a free user on PythonAnywhere you'd be restricted to HTTP/HTTPS
only, to a whitelist of sites. Because most email services work over SMTP,
which is not HTTP or HTTPS, that means you cannot use SMTP as free user.

If you want to send email, you have [two options](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SMTPForFreeUsers/): use an HTTP/HTTPS-based email
service or use Gmail's SMTP servers.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and used App-specific passwords. Which solved the issue. You can do it by going to Gmail account Settings > Security > Signing into Google.

First, you have to Turn on 2-Step Verification. Then App-specific password option will appear. Create a password by specifying the app as custom/other and specifying a name.
Use that password in your SMTP code.